# How to display table cell content in a modal in JS?

Tags: html

```
<?php 
    $programs[] = array( "episode_title" => (string)$path_title_en, 
        "episode_title_fr" => (string)$path_title_fr; 
 }      
?>
```

I am working on html table rows as shown below in which I am adding an ellipsis at **LineA** and **LineB** (as I don't want to show the entire content) and parsing it into table element (td).

```
 <?php 
       foreach ($programs as $key => $program)    { 
  ?>
    <tr data-index="<?php echo $key; ?>">
       <?php
        $program["episode_title"] = substr($program["episode_title"],0,50).' <a href="">(...)</a>';        // Line A
        $program["episode_title_fr"] = substr($program["episode_title_fr"],0,50).' <a href="">(...)</a>';  // Line B
        ?>
       <td><?php echo $program["episode_title"]; ?></span></td>         // Line C                                                    
      <td><?php echo $program["episode_title_fr"]; ?></span></td>      // Line D
    </tr>
  <?php 
    }
?>
```

I have used **Line A** and **Line B** at  Line C and Line D.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what JS I need to add on click of **...**, entire content **belonging to that cell element shows up in the modal**

Answer (score 0):

First don't overwrite original contents, make a new variables instead. Than add onclick event and call `show_modal` function with param (text what you want to show).

```
$episode_title    = substr($program["episode_title"],   0,50).' <a href="" onclick="return show_modal(' . $program["episode_title"]    . ')">(...)</a>';  // Line A
$episode_title_fr = substr($program["episode_title_fr"],0,50).' <a href="" onclick="return show_modal(' . $program["episode_title_fr"] . ')">(...)</a>';  // Line B
```

Line C/D will call new variables.

```
<td><?php echo $episode_title; ?></span></td>         // Line C                                                    
<td><?php echo $episode_title_fr; ?></span></td>      // Line D
```

Function `show_modal` will be like

```
function show_modal(text) {
    $('#modal').html(text).show();

    return false;
}
```

Or you can call any jQuery modals of course. It doesn't matter, I don't know what you're already use.

Comment: Testing. Stay tuned.